# How to execute a local bash script on remote server via ssh with nohup

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, nohup

I can run a local script on a remote server using the `-s` option, like so:

```
# run a local script without nohup...
ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "bash -s" < myLocalScript.sh;
```

And I can run a remote script using `nohup`, like so:

```
# run a script on server with nohup...
ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "nohup bash myRemoteScript.sh > results.out 2>&1 &"
```

But can I run my local script with `nohup` on the remote server? I expect the script to take many hours to complete so I need something like `nohup`. I know I can copy the script to the server and execute it but then I have to make sure I delete it once the script is complete, would rather not have to do that if possible.

I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
# run a local script without nohup...
ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "nohup bash -s > results.out 2>&1 &" < myLocalScript.sh;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything special - Once you kick off a script on another machine, it should finish running even if you terminate the connection:

For example

```
ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "bash -s > results.out 2>&1" < myLocalScript.sh &

# Please wait a few seconds for the connection to be established
kill $! # Optional: Kill the last process
```

If you want to test it, try a simple script like this

```
# myLocalScript.sh
echo 'File created - sleeping'
sleep 30
echo 'Finally done!'
```

The `results.out` file should immediately be created on the other machine with "File created - sleeping" in it. You can actually kill the local ssh process with `kill <your_pid>`, and it will **still** keep running on the other machine, and after 30 seconds, print "Finally done!" into the file, and exit.

Comment: That leaves the SSH connection open for the duration of the script, and will probably kill it with a SIGHUP if the background SSH job should terminate for whatever reason. You really want to background the script on the remote side instead.

Comment: Yes, it does leave the ssh connection open, but you can kill it immediately with `kill $!`, if you want. It does not need to remain open, and closing it changes nothing - the script will continue to execute on the remote machine.

Comment: That's not my experience. A `nohup bash -s` behaves like that for me, though.

Comment: Honestly - I was surprised. I was going to give this as a *negative* example, for what not to do, but it works perfectly. I've tried it several times, and I cannot make the process stop on the remote server, no matter what I do on the local server.

Comment: You're right! I tried your suggestion and the script still completes. Got to say I'm very surprised, I was certain the process would be killed as soon as the `ssh` connection was broken, hence the need for `nohup`.